# How to integrate highcharts in spago bi studio 5.2

Tags: highcharts, spagobi

As Highchart license is CC, SpagoBI stops include highcharts as default one from version 5.2. However SpagoBI wiki having documentation about howto include HighChart in SpagoBI server. I didn't find documentation to include HighChart in SpagoBI Studio. Therefore we are having only JFreeChart and ExtChart in IDE.

Any Idea, how to include Highchart in SpagoBI studio? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also i have this very question.